# get_the_term_list() wanting to loop through the returned values

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, taxonomy, terms

I have a custom post type, I am echoing out my custom taxonomies in my template by doing the following, `get_the_term_list( get_the_ID(), 'work', '<li>', "", '</li>')` , this currently returns "Design", what I am wanting to do, is the following, for the first value that it is found I want to do the following,

`<li><a href="the taxonomies link"> Find out more about Taxonomy Name</a></li>`

for the second value (if there is a 2nd) I would like the do the following

`<li><a href="the taxonomies link">How Taxonomy Name can benefit you</a></li>`

Basically how ever many taxonomies there I only want to show 2 and I want to be able to use them as above? Is this even possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use `wp_get_object_terms` which will return an array of object terms that you can manipulate. You also have a little more control with sorting the terms.

```
<?php
$terms = wp_get_object_terms($post->ID, 'work', array('orderby' => 'name', 'order' => 'ASC'));
if(is_array($terms)) : ?>
<ul>
    <?php if(isset($terms[0])) : ?><li><a href="<?php echo get_term_link($terms[0]); ?>">Find out more about <?php echo $terms[0]->name; ?></a></li><?php endif; ?>
    <?php if(isset($terms[1])) : ?><li><a href="<?php echo get_term_link($terms[1]); ?>">How  <?php echo $terms[1]->name; ?> can benefit you</a></li><?php endif; ?>
</ul>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Obviously, this is not a very dynamic solution and will only work for your first two terms, but these functions should help you sort out the correct solution for you.